# How to check if IMapiFolder is built in or a user defined folder

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

When using MAPI to access folders in Outlook, how can I know from the IMapiFolder object whether the folder is a built in folder (e.g. Inbox, Outbox, Calendar) or a user defined one? (I want to access only user defined folders)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the entry ids of the folders that you want to exclude and compare them with the entry id of the folder in question using `IMAPISession::CompareEntryIDs`.

Comment: thanks - I see in MFCMapi how to retrieve EntryIDs. I now also encounter in a folder named "PersonMetadata" which seems to be a built-in folder, although I cannot see it anywhere (but it's retrieved when enumerating all folders). I'm not sure what this folder is and I cannot find info on it. is there a way to retrieve its EntryID in order to exclude it?

Comment: Is it actually under the IPM subtree? Can the user see it?

Comment: yes, but the user cannot see it (it's an outlook account connected to office365)

Comment: Where exactly is the folder located relative to other folders?

Comment: it's top level under the account - same as Inbox

Comment: Check to make sure PR_ATTR_HIDDEN on the folder is missing or set to false. Otherwise don't show the folder to the end user.